# AS3 - my sound player seems to work well but the sound is not there

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio

I've been doing a soundplayer for my assignment.Came across some issues. No compile error neither runtime error is appearing and my sound player functions well but I can't hear the song playing.

```
var mySound:Sound = new Sound ();
var myURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest ("playList.xml");
var mySoundChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel;
var playing:Boolean = true;
var resumeTime:Number = 0;
var loadedXML:XML;
var mySongs:XMLList;
var myTotal:Number;
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();

myXMLLoader.load(myURL);
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
function processXML (e:Event):void {
    loadedXML = XML(e.target.data);
    mySongs = loadedXML.SONG; 
    myTotal = mySongs.length();
}

btnPlayPause.buttonMode =true;
btnStop.buttonMode =true;
btnPlayPause.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playSound);
btnStop.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, stopSound);

function playSound(m:MouseEvent){
    if(playing==true){
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPause");
        mySound.load(myURL);
        mySoundChannel = mySound.play(resumeTime);
        playing = false;
    } else {
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPlay");
        resumeTime = mySoundChannel.position;
        mySoundChannel.stop();
        playing = true;
    }   
}

function stopSound (f:MouseEvent):void {
    mySoundChannel.stop();
}
```

Help is appreciated very much.

Comment: Add `IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR` and `ProgressEvent.PROGRESS` listeners to the sounds so you can check what's going on :) You may also add SecurityError event..

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you trying to play sound only if it already playing, while stoping sound if it is NOT playing:

```
function playSound(m:MouseEvent){
    if(playing==true){
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPause");
        mySound.load(myURL);
        mySoundChannel = mySound.play(resumeTime);
        playing = false;
    } else {
        btnPlayPause.gotoAndStop("lbPlay");
        resumeTime = mySoundChannel.position;
        mySoundChannel.stop();
        playing = true;
    }   
}
```

I see this code like this:

```
function playSound(){
    if(playing){
        mySound.play();
    } else {
        mySoundChannel.stop();
    }   
}
```

Maybe this is the root of problem